# How much maintenance is required to run a WordPress server?

Tags: updates, upgrade, maintenance

I recently started a blog at wordpress.com, but I am considering moving to a self-hosted WordPress to get access to plugins such as MathJax and Markdown and probably several others I will discover along the way. I am reluctant to do so, because running at my own website will inevitable require some maintenance (I will not be maintaining the HW, just using some standard webhosting service).

How much work is required to maintain WordPress? That is, how often are there security updates and new versions that you will probably want? How difficult are updates to perform?

Comment: From what I hear so far, it does not sound like that much of a hassle. Seriously considering it...

Answer (score 2):

> How much work is required to maintain WordPress?

If you are not maintaining the server itself, very little. Even actual server maintenance doesn't usually take that much time though.

> That is, how often are there security updates and new versions that
>   you will probably want?

Basically, you want every release. I would not advise skipping releases or trying to apply only the releases that look important. Sometimes the releases come faster than I'd like. I'd much prefer a different release model but no use worrying about what isn't likely to change. I'd guess you'd need to update twice or three times a year. Releases seem to be coming a bit faster than they used to but I haven't actually looked at the dates.

> How difficult are updates to perform?

Remarkably easy. I tend not to use the automatic updater and go with the manual update because I can run the release locally before uploading, then upload the tested code as a whole. Still, not difficult and I have never really had a serious issue with an update, though you do see people report update problems so they happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can check archive of WP versions (with release dates) here: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions

Upgrading WP is pretty easy. WordPress will notify you when new version is available. It will allow you to upgrade automatically with one mouse click.

There are 2 other things you should remember:

1. You should keep your plugins up to date too.
2. You should always do backup before doing any updates. If you will use good plugins and well-written theme, everything should be fine, but sometimes there are some problems with updates and having backup is really nice in such cases.